# J2NET.Runtime could not be found. Please check if the runtime is installed for your platform

Tags: java, jdbc, .net-6.0

I want to use JDBC.Net.Data on my project.
In .Net Core 6 console application it works but when I try it in a .Net Core 6 Web API I get the error below.

> "J2NET.Runtime could not be found. Please check if the runtime is installed for your platform."

Everything is similar in both projects.

The problem is, In Web App, Kesrel can't access the JRE files which is included in the bin/debug/net6.0/runtimes folder.

But in my console application, everything is same as web app, even the folder structures.

How can I set my web app to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you. After searching through their github, I found this was identified as an issue on 06/01/2023. The project owner published a fix in the latest version 1.3.0.

[evan-choi commented 06/01/2023](https://github.com/chequer-io/J2NET/issues/1#issuecomment-1571261751)

Please upgrade your package dependencies to v1.3.0.

[Also be aware the package names have changed](https://github.com/chequer-io/J2NET#2-add-runtime-package-reference)

`J2NET.Runtime.Win64` is now `J2NET.Runtime.win-x64`

Doing the upgrade got me past the runtime error, but then, another error occurred: `"A task has been cancelled"`. After stepping through the JDBC.Net source code the `var process = JavaRuntime.Execute(javaRunArgs);` (in `Models\JdbcBridge.cs`) immediately exits, and they cancel the task. I found that the java runtime cannot find the `JDBC.NET.Bridge.jar` in the asp.net core project execution directory. So i put in a pull request to fix that and fully qualify the path to the jar files.

[Support ASP.Net Core #29](https://github.com/chequer-io/JDBC.NET/pull/29)

You can wait for evan to complete the pull request and publish another nuget package or you can include their source into your project like I did, and then add my code. You then may have to copy `JDBC.NET.Bridge.jar` from the console app exe directory to `JDBC.NET.Bridge\target` as `JDBC.NET.Bridge-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` (for debug, or just `JDBC.NET.Bridge.jar` in release).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try and let you know.