# JDBC.NET returns "Task Cancelled" error on .NET 6 Web App

Tags: .net, jdbc, .net-6.0

I am trying to create a JDBC connection using JDBC.NET library in my .NET 6 Web App in Azure.

I have followed the instructions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76052007/j2net-runtime-could-not-be-found-please-check-if-the-runtime-is-installed-for-y) but the application keeps returning "Task was Cancelled" error.

I replicated the SAMPLE console app [provided here](https://github.com/chequer-io/JDBC.NET)
The console app works fine, even the .NET 6 API works fine locally
But after deployment it returns "A Task was Cancelled" error.